# meaning of "partially includes"

Tags: meaning

What does

> X partially includes Y.

mean?

1. X includes parts of Y, but not all of it.
2. X includes all of Y, and even more.
3. Depending on the context, either could be possible.

Comment: Please don't use X and Y, but use the actual words or examples.

Answer (score 1):

> X partially includes Y.

always means:

> 1. X includes parts of Y, but not all of it.

Additionally, X can include / contain other stuff, not related to Y.

It becomes even more obvious is we re-phrase it to the passive voice:

> Y is partially included in X.

Answer (score 0):

X includes here Y in some *incomplete* form (parts, pieces, some area, etc.)
Case '2' would be true with the similar-looking word '*parti**cular**ly*' (X includes Y and something else).